# Interpretation of $\mathbb P(A|X=x)$ in two ways

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X:(\Omega,\mathscr A) \to (\mathbb R,\mathscr{B})$ be a random variable between two measurable spaces (the latter being the Borel measurable space over $\mathbb R$). Let $x\in \mathbb R$. Let $\mathbb P$ be a probability on $(\Omega,\mathscr A)$. Assuming $\mathbb P(X=x)\ne 0$ ,I have two interpretations for $\mathbb P(A|X=x)$:

(1) Naive definition: Simply use the elementary definition of the conditional probability:

$$\mathbb P(A|X=x)=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap[X=x])}{\mathbb P([X=x])}.$$

(2) Official definition of such conditional probability:

$$\mathbb P(A|X=x)=\mathbb E(\mathbb 1_A|X=x)=\varphi(x),$$

where the conditional probability $\mathbb E(\mathbb 1_A|X=x)=\varphi(x)$ is defined via the "factorization lemma", which states that there exists a measurable $\varphi:(\mathbb R,\mathscr{B})\to (\mathbb R,\mathscr{B})$ such that $\varphi(X)=\mathbb E(\mathbb 1_A|X):=\mathbb E(\mathbb 1_A|\sigma(X))$. ($\mathbb E(\mathbb 1_A|\sigma(X))$ is the conditional probability in the usual sense).

The definition in (2) can be found for example in Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course, by Achim Klenke, page 180-181.

Do the conditional probabilities in (1) and (2) agree (at least almost surely)? If they only agree under some further assumptions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the set $G := \{\omega: X(\omega) = x\}$ has positive probability, by conditional probability definition, $\varphi(X)$ satisfies
$$P(A \cap G) = \int_G \varphi(X(\omega))dP = \int_{\{x\}}\varphi(y)\mu(dy) = \varphi(x)\mu{(\{x\})} = \varphi(x)P[X = x],$$
where $\mu$ is the induced probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B})$.

In above, the second equality follows the change-of-variable formula. The third equality follows the definition of integration.

Hence your conjecture is correct, as it should be.

Comment: The OP clearly says he wanted to consider the case $P(X = x) \neq 0$. Read the question more carefully. In addition, my answer starts with the statement "Given that ... has positive probability". When you make some judgement, you need to be more cautious. From your answer, I can tell you didn't understand OP's question well. Did you really see what he tried to ask?

Comment: And where did you see I said $P(A | \sigma(X))$ and $P[A | \{X = x\}]$ are same objects?

Comment: My apologies, I was at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space.

**(2) is the correct definition**. $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|X=x]$ is notation used to denote the  (almost surely) value of $g(\omega)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|\sigma(X)](\omega)$ when $X(\omega)=x$.

**Your naive definition (1)** is not entirely correct.  There is an unfortunate abuse of notation that has propragated since time imemorial; $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|B]$ really means is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|\sigma(\mathbb{1}_B)]$, where $\sigma(\mathbb{1}_B)=\{\emptyset,B,\Omega\setminus B,\Omega\}$.  With this is mind, a simple computation shows
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|B]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}\mathbb{1}_B +
\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\setminus B]}{\mathbb{P}[\Omega\setminus B]}\mathbb{1}_{\Omega\setminus B}\tag{1}\label{one}
$$
Of course, if $\mathbb{P}[B]=0$ then  $\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}$ is not defined, but this problem happened in a set of measure zero ($B$) and in this case  $\eqref{one}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|B]=1$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

In particular, if $B=\{X=x\}$, $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|\{X=x\}]=\frac{P[A\cap\{X=x\}]}{\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}]}\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}+\frac{P[A\cap\{X=x\}]}{\mathbb{P}[\{X \neq x\}]}\mathbb{1}_{\{X\neq x\}}$ with the caveat that when $\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}]=0$, the indetity interpreted as $1$ a.s.

---

Finally, if $x$ is such that $\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}]>0$ then
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|\sigma(X)]\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap\{X=x\}]}{\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}]}\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}
$$
To see this, test against any set $\{X\in C\}$ ($C$ Borel)
$$
\int \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|\sigma(X)]\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{X\in C\}}\, d\mathbb{P}=\int \mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{X\in C\}}\, d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}[A\cap\{X=x\}\cap\{X\in C\}]
$$
this equals $\mathbb{P}[A\cap\{X=x\}]$ if $x\in C$ and $0$ other wise. On the other hand
$$
\int \frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap\{X=x\}]}{\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}]}\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{X\in C\}}\,d\mathbb{P}= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap\{X=x\}]\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}\cap\{X\in C\}]}{\mathbb{P}[\{X=x\}]}
$$
which equals $\mathbb{P}[A\cap\{X=x\}]$ if $x\in C$ and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The Naïve definition is undefined when $\Bbb P([X=x])=0$.  Otherwise they agree.